# Javascript Elements with class / variable ID

Tags: javascript, vbscript, automation

There's a page with some HTML as follows:

```
<dd id="fc-gtag-VARIABLENAMEONE" class="fc-content-panel fc-friend">
```

Then further down the page, the code will repeat with, for example:

```
<dd id="fc-gtag-VARIABLENAMETWO" class="fc-content-panel fc-friend">
```

How do I access these elements using an external script?

I can't seem to use document.getElementByID correctly in this instance. Basically, I want to search the whole page using oIE (InternetExplorer.Application Object) created with VBScript and pull through every line (specifically VARIABLENAME(one/two/etc)) that looks like the above two into an array.

I've researched the Javascript and through trial and error haven't gotten anywhere with this specific page, mainly because there's no tag name, and the tag ID always changes at the end. Can someone help? :)

EDIT: I've attempted to use the Javascript provided as an answer to get results, however nothing seems to happen when applied to my page. I  think the  tag is ALSO in a  tag so it's getting complicated - here's a major part of the code from the webpage I will be scanning.

```
<dd id="fc-gtag-INDIAN701" class="fc-content-panel fc-friend">
    <div class="fc-pic">
        <img src="http://image.xboxlive.com/global/t.58570942/tile/0/20400" alt="INDIAN701"/>
    </div>
    <div class="fc-stats">
        <div class="fc-gtag">
            <a class="fc-gtag-link" href='/en-US/MyXbox/Profile?gamertag=INDIAN701'>INDIAN701</a>
            <div class="fc-gscore-icon">3690</div>
        </div>
        <div class="fc-presence-text">Last seen 9 hours ago playing Halo 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fc-actions">
        <div class="fc-icon-actions">
            <div class="fc-block">
                <span class="fc-buttonlabel">Block User</span>
                <a href="#" class="fc-blockbutton" onclick="return FriendCenter.BlockFriend('INDIAN701'); return false;"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fc-text-actions">
            <div class="fc-action">&nbsp;</div>
            <span class="fc-action">
                <a href="/en-US/MyXbox/Profile?gamertag=INDIAN701">View Profile</a>
            </span>
            <span class="separator-icon">|</span>
            <span class="fc-action">
                <a href="/en-US/GameCenter?compareTo=INDIAN701">Compare Games</a>
            </span>
            <span class="separator-icon">|</span>
            <span class="fc-action">
                <a href="/en-US/MessageCenter/Compose?gamertag=INDIAN701">Send Message</a>
            </span>
            <span class="separator-icon">|</span>
            <span class="fc-action">
                <a href="#" onclick="return FriendCenter.AddFriend('INDIAN701');">Send Friend Request</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</dd>
```

This then REPEATS, with a different username (the above username is INDIAN701).

I tried the following but clicking the button doesn't yield any results:

```
<script language="vbscript">
    Sub window_onLoad

      Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      oIE.visible = True
      oIE.navigate "http://live.xbox.com/en-US/friendcenter/RecentPlayers?Length=12"

    End Sub

</script>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var getem = function () {
      var nodes = oIE.document.getElementsByTagName('dd'),
      a = [];

      for (i in nodes) {
          (nodes[i].id) && (nodes[i].id.match(/fc\-gtag\-/)) && (a.push(nodes[i]));
      }
      alert(a[0].id);
      alert(a[1].id);
    }
</script> 

<body>

<input type="BUTTON" value="Try" onClick="getem()">


</body>
```

Basically I'm trying to get a list of usernames from the recent players list (I was hoping I wouldn't have to explain this though :)   ).

Comment: is the player name in the anchor tags that have a class of "fc-gtag-link"?

Comment: at the end of the playername which is what I want, it has class="fc-content-panel fc-friend"

Comment: I'd like to note to everyone that the use of an iFrame doesn't work, because the xbox webpage requires a login(https). This is why vbscript dims oIE as the InternetExplorer.Application object to reference in VBScript. However, this is not in Javascript so I don't know how to access this from Javascript. Still no solution, any takers? Entirely Javascript would work too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var getem = function () {
        var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('dd'),
            a = [];

        for (var i in nodes) if (nodes[i].id) {
            (nodes[i].id.match(/fc\-gtag\-/)) && (a.push(nodes[i].id.split('-')[2]));
        }
        alert(a[0]);
    };
```

[please try it by clicking here!](http://jsbin.com/ovidej)

Comment: This also doesn't give any alerts :(

Comment: I understand how the javascript works through clicking the link - appreciate that little addition. I believe the error I'm getting is that I created the variable (as you can see in my script above) oIE from VBScript - as an InternetExplorer.Application object. The problem here is, I don't know how to reference this in my Javascript. oIE.document.getElementsByTagName('dd') does not work!

Comment: try this (notice the capital 'D'): oIE.Document.getElementsByTagName('dd')

Comment: Nope, no alert with the capital D either unfortunately :(

Comment: if you click on my name do you see my email address?

Answer (score 1):

```
var getem = function () {
    var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('dd'),
        a = [];

    for (var i in nodes) if (nodes[i].id) {
        (nodes[i].id.match(/fc\-gtag\-/)) && (a.push(nodes[i]));
    }
    alert(a[0].id);
    alert(a[1].id);
};
```

[try it out on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eloxok/4/)

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, as it's in simple Javascript with a Regex... but I'm not sure the code is working for what I want. I may have not given enough information, therefore I've updated the above post if you would be so kind as to take another look :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var outputSpan = document.getElementById('outputSpan'),
                iFrame = frames['subjectIFrame'];

            iFrame.document.location.href = 'http://live.xbox.com/en-US/friendcenter/RecentPlayers?Length=1';
            (function () {
                var nodes = iFrame.document.getElementsByTagName('dd'),
                a = [];
                for (var i in nodes) if (nodes[i].id) {
                    (nodes[i].id.match(/fc\-gtag\-/)) && (a.push(nodes[i].id.split('-')[2]));
                }
                for (var j in a) if (a.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                    outputSpan.innerHTML += (a[j] + '<br />');
                }
            })();
        };
    </script>
    <span id="outputSpan"></span>
    <iframe id="subjectIFrame" frameborder="0" height="100" width="100" />
</body>
```

Comment: Because the XBOX.com website requires a LOGIN to (https here) access the recent players list, this cannot be displayed in an iFrame. Really appreciate your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

What does "I can't seem to use document.getElementsByID correctly in this instance" mean?  Are you referring to the fact that you are misspelling `getElementByID`?

Comment: That's merely a mistake in me typing it up, not in my code. Thanks for pointing it out though!

Answer (score 0):

So...something like this (jQuery)?

```
var els = [];

$('.fc-content-panel.fc-friend').each(function() {
  els.push(this));
});
```

Now you have an array of all the elements that have both of those classes.

Comment: Might I suggest `var els = $('.fc-content-panel.fc-friend').get()`, which does the same thing.

Comment: @Malvolio: Cool, I had no idea about that. You learn something every day!

Comment: Yes, that is a risk.  Try sleeping late.