# JS Elements in different window

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to open another website and pull out a list of usernames on that site to send a message to. Specifically, I'm talking about `XBOX Live` previous players - this requires a login through a `https://` website and so an iFrame so that Javascript can reference this cannot be used.

I have looked at `JavaScript HTML DOM` Examples but none of them seem to be what I need.

How do I create a NEW window in `Javascript` and access the elements of that window?

You can see my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926656/javascript-elements-with-class-variable-id) where I was attempting to do this with `VBScript` (an appalling idea really). Show me how I can perform the same with pure Javascript! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the window is in a different domain, JavaScript can not access it because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). So for the same reason you can not do it with an iframe, you can not do it with a pop up window.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you point out any alternative methods or languages I can take a look at?

Comment: Not going to happen with JavaScript on the client unless the other site offers an api. Better off learning a serverside language [php, python, java, ruby, .net, node.js, etc].